# How to fit a convex curve to set of data points

Tags: c#, math, curve, curve-fitting

I have a set of data points (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) etc. The data is such that slope of successive points are increasing most of the time. But there are a few exceptions. The software I load the data into expects that the slope should always increase or in other words that the curve should be convex. So, I need a result set of data points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) etc such that the it removes the "exception" data points and replace them with  appropriate data points which causes the slope to always increase.

I was going to write a program (in C#) to do this but I thought I would post here to check if this is a standard problem and solutions may already exist.

Comment: Do you mean you want to assert that the slope from `P2 -> P3` is always greater than the slope from `P1 -> P2`?

Comment: If (P2, P3) slope is not great than (P1, P2), I want to remove P3 and replace P3 with some appropriate value (possibly (P4 +P2)/2) so that with the new P3, slope is increasing.

Comment: Oh, are there always more than 3 points? (P4 or more?)  What if the slope is equal (linear)?  EDIT: If there are more than 3 points, do all successive points need to be checked?

Comment: There are around 32 data points. Yes. All points need to be checked. Equal slopes are exceptions too. So In my previous comment, P4 may have to be removed too and both P3 and P4 my have to be replaced. The exceptions are rare. i.e. may be 2 or 3 in the 32 data points

Comment: What do you mean by 'fit' ? Your notion of convex meaning that the slope always increases is incorrect. An ellipse is convex but its gradient changes. In order to get what you describe above, you could fit a quadratic least squares approximation with positive quadratic coefficient. This function has constantly increasing gradient AND is convex. See this link for convex function definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: mathematician1975, Thanks for pointing about the convex definition. If I do a least squares approx (which i tried with a sample set), it affects all my data points. Considering there are only 1 or 2 exceptions in my data set, I don't want it to change my other values. I think I might just have to do some kind of correction only to the "exception points".

Comment: I hope you aren't working on temperature readings. ;)

Comment: No they are actually trading data used for transaction cost modelling. (X,Y) = Share Size/Cost. But the optimizer which i feed the data has certain constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem depends on the objective. You could restrict yourself to changing the Y coordinates of the points, while keeping X fixed. Then, a reasonable objective might be to minimize the sum of the absolute differences ABS(Y'-Y) between your new Y-value Y' and old value Y, for each point. (I have no idea whether this is reasonable for your problem, but it does not sound very unreasonable to me.)

Then the problem could be modelled as a linear program, see :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

There are standard libraries to find the optimal solution in such cases.